# Electron - passing argument from main.js to html

Tags: javascript, electron

I would like to pass an argument from main.js process to my html site on init.

I've tried several things, but it doesn't work. The goal is, to fill the formfield "username" with "123". I have marked, what I have added to realize this with #1 and #2. Any ideas, whats missing? thanks in advance!

Main.js

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow, session, ipcMain, webContents} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-features', 'OutOfBlinkCors');

function createWindow () {
  
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences : {
      webSecurity: false,
      nodeIntegration: true      
    }
  })

  
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
 
  //#1
  //Passing arguments 
  mainWindow.webContents.send('got-access-token', '123');
  
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})
```

Renderer.js

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
//#2
//Pass argument 
ipcRenderer.on("got-access-token", (event, accessToken) => {
    document.getElementById("username").value = accessToken;
});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login</h1>
        <!-- <form method="post">-->
            <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required" id="username"/><script> require("./renderer.js"); </script>
            <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" id="password"/>            
            <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Login ...</button>
       <!--  </form> -->
    </div>
    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main process

```
 ipcMain.on('request-token',(event)=>{

        event.reply('receive-token', token);
  })
```

In your renderer

In your main renderer

```
 ipcRenderer.on('receive-token',(accessToken)=>{
        console.log('token received')
     document.getElementById("username").value = accessToken;

  });

  ipcRenderer.send('request-token');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've changed this but am getting the error  ipcMain.send is not a function